# java cleanDirectory() how to make directory path OS idependent

Tags: java, junit, automation, selenide

Please, help me with solution. I'm testing the files downloading process and to clear up the Downloads directory using in @AfterClass cleanDirectory() on MAC OS

```
@AfterClass
public static void clearDownloadDirectory() throws IOException{
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("/Users/irina/Downloads"));
}
```

How to make the Downloads directory path platform independent so it could work for Windows too?

Maybe I'm looking for the answer in a wrong way. Primary thing I need is to delete all xlsx files from the Downloads folder.

Comment: Wow... as a developer, I would surely be pissed if building some piece of software deleted MY downloads directory. Why don't you create (and delete) a temp directory?

Comment: Makes sense... I just need to figure out how to direct the downloading files to temp folder and not the default one as it used in Chrome brobser

Comment: I'm not deleting the Downloads directory, I'm deleting all dowloaded files in it.

Comment: For what reason? Are you creating a "cleaner" application? And even then, give the user an option to specify the directory, you don't know if the user changes the director in chrome (maybe you can read out that info). And if you download something for your app (like an update) use a temp folder.

Comment: It is not the application. I'm creating and running UI automated tests which download a file after particular actions and I need to delete all downloaded files in xlsx format after test run completes just to clean up the local folder and avoid doing it manually.

Comment: whats wrong with using an internal folder within the applications directory? Why do you need to specifically use the standard download folder?

Comment: There are also libraries that already solve this issue, like e.g. https://github.com/dirs-dev/directories-jvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your app you can use `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

Maybe like this

```
//...
String url;
switch( System.getProperty("os.name") ) {
    case "Windows 8.1":
    case "Windows Vista":
    //etc for all windows systems
    {
      url = "C:/Users/user_name/downloads..."
      break;
    }
    case "Mac OS X": //...
    case "SunOS": //...
    case "Linux": //...
    //etc all systems you want to support
}
```

**EDIT**

Also `System.getProperty("user.home")` can help you

> "user.home"   User home directory

[Java System properties list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: Maybe, there is some kind of environmental variable so i could write it in path to folder?

Comment: Check my edit and try not to use environmental variables.

Comment: Thanks, going to try your variant

Comment: Thanks again, this variant worked for me  `public static void clearDownloadDirectory() throws IOException {
        String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(home+"/Downloads"));
    }`  The only thing I had troubles with is when I tries to apply exact file format (new File(home+"/Downloads/" + ".xlsx")); there was en error that such file does not exist

Comment: Happy to help! Make sure you provide correct filename to your File constructor. Missing in your comment... `home + "/Downloads/" + ".xlsx"` is just `.../Downdloads/.xlsx`. Happy coding!